# EF code first cannot convert type to int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am creating a function on my restaurant review website that gets the cuisine of the last review and then finds other reviews with same cuisine that have a higher average score. It then saves every restaurant id in a database. However I keep on receiving the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'int'` on the line `where r.id = samecuisine`.

Any help would be grateful.

```
var samecuisine = (from r in db.Reviews
                   where r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine
                   select r.id);

var pick = (from r in db.Reviews
            where r.id = samecuisine
            select r.score).Average();

var choices = (from r in db.Reviews
               where r.score >= pick
               select r.RestaurantId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear why you'd want to get a review ID at all. You're only interested in the scores for those reviews, right? I suspect you *actually* want to take part of your first query and part of your second:

```
var averageScoreForCuisine = (from r in db.Reviews
                              where r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine
                              select r.score).Average();
```

Or to my mind more readably:

```
var averageScoreForCuisine = db.Reviews
                               .Where(r => r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine)
                               .Average(r => r.score);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query

```
var samecuisine = (from r in db.Reviews
                   where r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine
                   select r.id);
```

returns an `IQueryable<int>`, not an actual `int`.

Try to retrieve the `.FirstOrDefault()`, this yields the first result (or the default value 0).